# lftp from linux to a Mainframe (secure connection tls 1.2)

Tags: lftp

We are sending a file from the Linux (client) to the Mainframe (server) using lftp.

In the mainframe, we can see the following messages when it fails:

```
Aug 24 14:03:38 MVSSYSD/ODPFTP   ODPFTP   ftps[33556275]: SR3535 reply: --> 425-Server requires protected data connection.
Aug 24 14:03:38 MVSSYSD/ODPFTP   ODPFTP   ftps[33556275]: SR3535 reply: --> 425 Can't open data connection.
```

On the Linux side, we see similar messages:

```
425 - server requires protected data connection
425 can't open data connection
closing data socket
```

Is there a way to make the lftp client in the unix to use "protected data connection"?